# django models field that is different for every user

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, django, django-channels

I have a model called post and I want to check if a user has liked that post. I want to do it by adding a boolean field in post model that changing it doesn't affect another user. So if user 1 changes it to true for all other users it will be false. Is that possible?

Comment: Read up on ManyToMany relations. May users can like a post and many posts can be liked by one user. A user has a query-able set of likes and a post has a query-able set of liked-bys.

Answer (score 0):

You need one more table to represent this relation.

Consider this solution.

```
class PostLike(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='likes')
    
    # to ensure one like per user
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('user', 'post')
```

When user likes the post you create an instance of this model that links user to post.

If instance exists then post is liked by user.

Comment: But isn't that bad for perfomance because when you map through the posts you have to check if that instance exists for every single post

Comment: Isn't that exactly what you want? When displaying posts you want to show that post was liked right? You can use `select_related` or `prefetch_related` to optimize it.